# Spring boot application form is not validating on the given validations

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

```
@Entity
public class People {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Please enter Phone Number")
    private long phoneNumber;

//getters and setters
}
```

For the above model class, my jsp page is not showing any default error message or the one provided to it.
The form is getting submitted somehow.
I've added `@valid` annotation in the post route.

Also, i've added this dependencies

```
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Post Route

```
@Valid
    @PostMapping("/emergency-complaint")
    public String emergencyComplaintIndexPost(@Valid People people, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "emergency-complaint/index";
        }
        return "home";
    }
```

Form Jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>CRS | Kolkata</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:errors path="people.*" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
        <div>
            <h1>Lodge an Emergency Complaint Now!!</h1>
            <form:form
                action="/emergency-complaint"
                method="post"
                modelAttribute="people"
            >
                <form:label path="emergencyComplaint.complaint" for="complaint">
                    Emergency Complaint
                </form:label>
                <form:input
                    type="text"
                    name="complaint"
                    id="complaint"
                    path="emergencyComplaint.complaint"
                />

                <form:label path="name" for="name">Name</form:label>
                <form:input path="name" type="text" name="name" id="name" />

                <form:label path="phoneNumber" for="phoneNumber"
                    >Phone Number</form:label
                >
                <form:input
                    path="phoneNumber"
                    type="Number"
                    name="phoneNumber"
                    id="phoneNumber"
                />

                <button type="submit">Lodge</button>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.naha</groupId>
  <artifactId>crime-reporting-system</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validation-api` is the `Bean Validation` specification API, it is not an implementation. You need to have an implementation (for example, Hibernate Validator) in your classpath.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497795/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-validation-doesnt-work/52657881#52657881) answer.

Also there is need to put `@Valid` on your handler method here.

Comment: It worked, but i have to add `@Valid`. As if i remove, it is throwing an error.

Comment: Also, for some weird reason, `@NotNull` is not working.

Comment: You have two `@Valid`s. You only need the one on the command object, inside the handler method parameter.

Comment: You are usning `@NotNull` for a primitive filed, `long`. But `long` cannot be null. Change to `Long`.